# How to find out the current number of threads in Azure?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azureservicebus, azure-diagnostics

I have a `QueueClient` that receives messages from the service bus, and spawns threads that process those messages:

```
var options = new OnMessageOptions();
options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;

// Use of Service Bus OnMessage message pump.
_client.OnMessageAsync(
    async (msg) =>
    {
        // Will block the current thread if Stop is called.
        await ProcessMessageAsync(processStream, msg);
    },
    options);
```

I know that the maximum amount of threads this can spawn is 10, as specified in the options. Is there a way of knowing how many threads CURRENTLY exist?

Bonus question: Is it possible to monitor the memory usage of those threads (individual or collective)?

Thanks

Comment: How many threads *where*?  In your application, on the virtual machine the app is running on, how many threads are processing messages?

Answer (score 1):

Value specified in MaxConcurrentCalls option doesn't equate to dedicated threads running in the process. It indicates how many parallel asynchronous receive requests are queued up to the Service Bus service. Once the async requests completes the result is processed on a callback thread. If the queue has a lot of messages and you specified MaxConcurrentCalls = 10 , then in theory there could be upto 10 threads calling OnMessageAsync.

Comment: I'm aware of this - the question is whether or not it is possible to obtain the current number of threads calling on OnMessageAsync() at any given point in time

Comment: One way you can do this is by adding a performance counter in the OnMessageAsync which get incremented on every invocation , call it "Inflight OnMessage Calls". Decrement this counter before leaving the method.